# Angular error on indexing "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null "

Tags: angular, typescript

Well this is little search app, search the value as per the key word.

App working perfect until I put if condition on `employee.name` and `employee.phone` but starting mess when I get more properties under if condition such as `employee.jobTitle` and `employee.email`.
What I want is, I could get result by `name`, `email`, `phone` and `jobTitle`.

Grateful if anyone can help me about what I missing here.

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.getEmployees();
   }

   public getEmployees():void {
     this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(
       (response: Employee[])=>{
         this.employees = response;
       },
       (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         alert(error.message);
       }
     );
   }

  public searchEmployees(key: string): void {
     console.log(key);
     const results: Employee[] = [];
     for (const employee of this.employees) {
       if (employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
       || employee.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
       || employee.phone.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
       || employee.jobTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
         results.push(employee);
       }
     }
     this.employees = results;
     if (results.length === 0 || !key) {
       this.getEmployees();
     }
   }
```

app.component.html

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
       <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input type="search" (ngModelChange)="searchEmployees(key.value)" #key="ngModel" 
        ngModel name="key" id="searchName" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search 
        employees..." required>
   </form>
   </div>
  </nav>

   
    <div *ngFor="let employee of employees" class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
                    <p>Name: {{employee?.name}}</p>
                    <p>Job title: {{employee?.jobTitle}}</p>
                <p>Email : {{employee?.email}}</p>
                <p> Phone : {{employee?.phone}}</p>
```

Comment: Could you provide a part of the code where you're getting `employee`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory:
If you see it after `employee.email.toLowerCase()` and `employee.jobTitle.toLowerCase()` just make sure the fields `employee.email` and `employee.jobTitle` are not null before calling `toLowerCase()` on them.

A possible fix could be this:

```
   if (employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
   || (employee.email && employee.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
   || employee.phone.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
   || (employee.jobTitle && employee.jobTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1))
```

---

**Update** regarding the second issue described in the comments:
Everytime after the search you lose your original employees array because in the end you do `this.employees = results;`.
So, next time when searching the search is done only in that reduced array instead of the original one.

To fix the issue I'd keep the original ones in another array like this:

`allEmployees: Employees[];`

Initialize that instead of `this.employees`:

```
   public getEmployees():void {
     ...
     // this.employees = response; // <- Remove this
     this.allEmployees = response; // <- Add this instead
     ...
   }
```

and always iterate over allEmployees instead of employees:

```
public searchEmployees(key: string): void {
   console.log(key);
   const results: Employee[] = [];
   for (const employee of this.allEmployees) { // <-- Replaced this.employees with this.allEmployees
     if (employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
       || (employee.email && employee.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
       || employee.phone.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
       || (employee.jobTitle && employee.jobTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1)) {
         results.push(employee);
     }
   }
   this.employees = results;
   if (results.length === 0 || !key) {
     this.getEmployees();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there is problem when I write John D in search i get all values = "john d" but when I remove D it doesn't getting back to all values = "john" but stay on "john d", any idea ?

Comment: @Just Shadow, optional chaining avoids the error but won't it return true on each !==1 condition?

Comment: Nice catch Kitsune66, thanks! @TheKash, updated the answer, please re-check...

Comment: @Just Shadow, many thanks, my 2nd problem is still remained. In my database i've 3 John with different last names i.e. John suliman,John Doe, John Mckenzie. If I search John these three appears if I put key "John M" I can get J...Macenzie... but I'm not getting back all three Johns when i remove word "Mackenzie"... thanks for the help

Comment: @TheKash seems like I've found the reason of that issue. Updated the answer to include that

Comment: @Just Shadow, Thanks for the efforts, but it doesn't work, bring an error TypeError: this.allemployees is not iterable. I copy full method "getEmployee" also. It has become challenge for you now.

Comment: What is the type of "this.employees"?

Comment: public employees: Employee[]; just blank property that's being filled up data (response) in getEmployees method

Comment: In `getEmployees()` try replacing `this.employees = ...` with `this.allEmployees = ...`

Comment: getting an error this.allemployees is not iterable

Comment: Then how the this.employees was iterable? Can you please put your code on https://stackblitz.com so we could debug? It would be easier

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the contents of the file ***tsconfig.json*** to

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
 "baseUrl": "./",
 "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "declaration": false,
 "downlevelIteration": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "module": "esnext",
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "importHelpers": true,
 "target": "es2015",
 "lib": [
   "es2018",
   "dom"
 ]
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
 "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
 "strictInjectionParameters": true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should try like this will solve this issue:

Declare variable.....

```js
public allEmployees!: Employee[];
```

Get full data retrieving.....

```js
public  getEmployees(): void{
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(
      (response: Employee[]) => {
        this.employees = response;
        this.allEmployees = response;
        console.log(this.employees);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
}
```

Assign to searching value.....

```js
public searchEmployees(key: string): void {
   console.log(key);
   const results: Employee[] = [];
   for (const employee of this.allEmployees) {
      if (employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
       || (employee.email && employee.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
       || employee.phone.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
       || (employee.jobTitle && employee.jobTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1)) {
         results.push(employee);
      }
   }
   this.employees = results;
   if (results.length > 1 || !key) {
      this.getEmployees();
   } else if (results.length === 0 || !key) {
      //Nothing to show for user
   }
}
```